# Magento: How to change orders statuses from any statuses to any states

Tags: magento

I would like to be free to set orders to any states totally free.

- cancel/refund any order
- revert shipped order
- revert issued order

For example.
It happens sometime i ship an order and then I want to revert this status.

Comment: start by defining the difference in states and statuses . State = state like US, Netherland ? Read your question and see if you can understand it yourself

Comment: in magento we have order Statuses and States ( give a look at System->Order Statuses

Answer (score 0):

You can set some status to some states on magento System -> Order Status.
And you vinculate each status can be seted to each state. 
By code you can do:

```
$order->setState();
$order->setStatus();
```

But uncancel its a little bit difficult. Take a look on that article and tell what you think. I implements this code and work, but i'm testing cuz this code can affect mutch thing and need lots of test to do it with safe.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/26245/viewthread/223219